# arcpy.polyline doesn't work properly

Tags: arcpy, polyline-creation

I'm sort of newbie to arcpy and trying to create a polyline based on the some predefined points which are put within "network_ND_Junctions1.shp". The code I've written seems like this:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\Users\\Erfan\\Desktop\\network_design"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput="true"

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(arcpy.env.workspace,"Routes.shp","POLYLINE")

route_list=[[2,1,0,4,10],[2,1,0,4,7,16,31,30,28,25,22,10]]

nodes_file="network_ND_Junctions1.shp"

for route in route_list:
    dictionary={}
    for node in route:
        dictionary[node]=[]

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(nodes_file,['FID','SHAPE@XY']) as cursor1:
        for row in cursor1:
            if row[0]in dictionary.keys():
                dictionary[row[0]].append(arcpy.Point(row[1][0],row[1][1]))

    myArray = arcpy.Array(dictionary.values())
    myline = arcpy.Polyline(myArray)
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor("Routes.shp",['SHAPE@']) as cursor2:
        newRow =[myline]
        cursor2.insertRow(newRow)

print myArray.count #output=2
print myline.pointCount #output=0
```

As you can see in the output comments, `arcpy.Array` works properly and contains two points but it seems that there's not any point within myline variable. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: **dont trust FIDs in a shapefile** they are subject to change without notice but that has nothing to do with your code. It seems your dictionary contains lists with a length of 1, this won't make a polyline. Can you try skipping the dictionary, replace dictionary={} with nList = [] then in the SearchCursor loop if row[0] in route: nList.append(arcpy.Point...) then myArray = arcpy.Array(nList), see if that will produce an output.

Comment: Please always specify the exact software in use. Even though the `arcpy.Polyline()` constructor makes the `spatial_reference` optional, it's a **crime** to not provide the `SpatialReference` from the target feature class in the constructor (because the default XY tolerance is used, which might collapse all your vertices to a single point).  Your debugging output isn't adequate to indicate what is happening -- In the future, try printing more information.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be part of your problem but:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput="true"
```

should be:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

because `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` needs to be set to a Boolean rather than a string.